# Orientation of vector space given that of its subspace and the associated quotient

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, tensor-products

In D. Freed's [lecture notes](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/dafr/M392C-2012/Notes/lecture2.pdf) pp.2 he mentions the following way to define the orientation of a vector space given that of its subspace and the associated quotient.

let $0 \to V' \to V \to V'' \to 0$ be a short exact sequence of finite dimensional real vector spaces, we can construct a canonical isomorphism of determinant lines $\text{Det}{V''} \otimes \text{Det}{V'} \to \text{Det}{V}$, where the determinant line of a vector space $V$ is defined by (where $\mathcal{B}(V)$ is the set of basis of $V$) $\text{Det}{V} = \{\epsilon: \mathcal{B}(V) \to \mathbb{R}|\epsilon(b \circ g) = \det(g)^{-1} \epsilon(b), \forall b \in \mathcal{B}(V), \forall g \in GL_n(\mathbb{R})\}$

If two out of the three of $V,V',V''$ are oriented then this isomorphism gives a unique orientation for the third one.

He emphasizes that the quotient is before the subspace i.e. it is $\text{Det}{V''} \otimes \text{Det}{V'} $ not $\text{Det}{V'} \otimes \text{Det}{V''}$ implying that the order matters. But I think Det$V$ is symtrivial (ref. [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/119689/classification-of-symtrivial-modules-over-a-pid)).  Am I right?

Comment: I guess I would think of $\det V$ as the top exterior power of $V$. It seems to me that his isomorphism is something like $\bar{w} \otimes v \mapsto w \wedge v$ and the order seems to matter quite a bit there. It's really more suggesting the order of the wedging, I think — of course $E \otimes F \simeq F \otimes E$.

Comment: @Hoot: I see.  Then that makes sense.  It is quite confusing here.  Many thanks Hoot!